# WPF three thumb slider?

Tags: c#, wpf, templates

May be you know a solution to implement tree thumb slider? I have one idea but it seems to be very sophisticated((.

Well, I dont know why my question is soo bad that it has -1 mark (???) I suppose it is not becouse it is difficult. Yes I need a THREE thumb slider. I need it for the histogramm control )). There is NO any more or less default controls in wpf that could work as histogramm. So I am writing it my own (the third variant - that is it =( - all previouse was not good for me) and I came here to find an idea what to do /

As for code - I have used for example this solution http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/ImageLevels_CustomControl.aspx
But his is NOT a three thumb slider  - this is more like three sliders together. Anyway I dont like it and now I am trying to write some MaGiC template to make SIMPLE three thumb slider.

Comment: What *is* that one idea? Show us what you tried; it's easier to help you when you do. (also, three-thumb slider? Isn't that a lot of thumbs to expect in a human?)

Comment: Like Piskvor said, we need to see code. I'm not even sure what a three-thumb slider is, but seeing code might make it clear.

Comment: Googling "tree thumb slider" returns this SO question...

Comment: @SomeWritesReserved Same with "thRee thumb slider". Wasn't even sure which one is the typo.

Comment: I Think its a valid question. Its a slider which has 3 thumbs, and not thumbs as in humans, thumbs as in WPF, get it? The left most thumb can never have a value greater than the other 2 thumbs on the same slider. Its to display a min value, a max value and an actual value.

Comment: One of the problems with this question is that no one has any idea what a three-thumb slider is. It looks like something fairly complicated and probably outside the scope of a SO question.

Comment: He's looking for a regular slider with two extra thumbs, one controlling the min value, and the other controlling the max.

Comment: @Papa John: I think modifying the code that you linked to is your best bet. It sounds like it already has most of what you want, you just need to modify the behavior to keep slider 1 below slider 2&3 and slider 2 below slider 3. I doubt anyone here is going to write you a custom slider control from scratch when there's a very usable template available.

Comment: This looks a lot like the gradient editor in Visual Studio / Blend for WPF.

Answer (score 4):

It should be fairly simple to implement. 
Create a Custom Control, add 3 dependency properties for your 3 thumb values. Maybe add the proper coercion for one thumb not exceding the value of the other thumbs. 
Now have a look of how the [Track](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.track.aspx) control in WPF works, you will need to implement something similiar to this control for your 3 way slider, which is properly the hardest part. A track having 3 Thumbs, disabling the vertical movement(or horizontal, depending on the orientation of the slider), deciding how to handle clicks on the track( simple slider makes the thumb jumping BigStep), moving only on the track, handling keyboard input, converting the positions into correct values etc..

Its difficult to tell more, without actually implementing it, but this would be the way i would start making it.
Maybe there is a way to make this in xaml with a lot of dirty bindings or template magic, but sometimes its perfectly valid to just create a new control.

Cheers